# Connecting ServerEndpoint to running program

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Problem: I have a Java program running on a Raspberry Pi accessing the camera that I would like to put in an HTML5 format instead of needing client software to communicate with the server, which is the current solution. The camera program needs to run regardless of whether someone is accessing the server or not.

Setup:

- The method of choice to send data between the host and client is Websockets using a Payara JavaEE server. Eventually, Payara Micro will be used on the R Pi.
- Camera program is debugged and works great
- **ServerEndpoint** java program works and can be debugged / deployed
- Camera and **ServerEndpoint** programs are in the same WAR file and deployed, however only the **ServerEndpoint** debuggable when deployed and accessed via a browser.

Question:

- **How the heck do I run the camera program and the server program and have the 2 communicate?** None of the examples show how to run a class with a Main function and a ServerEndpoint.
- Is there a better way to do this than how things are setup now?
- Gripe: there are so many web frameworks and project names and lingo in the Java server space, is there succinct summary of it all? Servlets vs. websockets vs. HttpRequest oh my!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days I finally found the answer. Basically, one needs to create an EAR file that is composed of the WAR project and an Enterprise Java Bean project (EJB).

The EAR project is an Enterprise Application project. All of this falls under Java EE.

This tutorial seemed the most comprehensive:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/index.htm